# Where to set origin of model space for solvePnP

Tags: opencv, model, coordinate-systems, pose-estimation

(Cross-posted from my question on OpenCV forum http://answers.opencv.org/question/100840/where-to-set-origin-of-model-for-solvepnp/)

Hi everyone, I've been figuratively tearing my hair out over this problem for over a month now. I have to admit that I haven't taken a good hard look at the math behind solvePnP (most people don't, which is why we have open source libraries), because reasons.

I'd like to ask for some practical advice regarding using solvePnP with regards to where to position the origin for the model.

Background: I'm using OpenCV to make a head tracking app. Tracking the objects (4 of them) on screen isn't really the problem; figuring out the 6DoF is.

Camera: Mobile phone camera. I haven't performed calibration, but I figure that as long as the subject keeps their head in the center of the view, it shouldn't be a big problem. I do notice significant barrel distortion towards the edges though.

Current results: Depending on where the model is "placed", I can get stable performance from *either* rotation or translation portions. Also, in odd cases, I get crazy results from different runs. Probably a singularity somewhere.

Parameters fed into solvePnP: Image points -- from tracker (origin in lower-left). Model points -- from 3D model (origin in lower-left, translated to OpenCV upper-left origin). Camera matrix -- fx,fy max dimension of image, principal point at center of image, no skew (may change if I do calibration). Using ITERATIVE with extrinsicGuess (because it's very jittery without it).

So the specific advice that I want to ask: Where should I set the origin of the model (in this case, of a human head) to get consistent 6DoF values? Ideally, I want to get the rotation values "anchored" inside the neck (about a few centimeters deep from the anterior). I've tried translating the head model points to have the origin inside the neck, but I notice that z-translation values go bonkers when a significant portion of the model is in the -z range. Also, it becomes unable to resolve x-rotation properly (it gives me positive values whether I look up or down).

Should I be placing the model in a particular octant of the model space? Should I avoid having any part of my model in the -z range, or should I expect solvePnP to return a -z translation for such a situation?

P.S. There are probably multiple separate problems in this question, and if you can address them that would be great too, but I'm most concerned about model placement in model space and its interactions with solvePnP

Answer (score 0):

The position of the origin should not matter much.  From my experience the relative positions of the object points is very important.  The group of points you select must be sensitive to all 6 degrees of freedom of the object (i.e. if you translate or rotate the object, the points must move in the image).  If there is not sufficient sensitivity in any degree of freedom the solver will be very twitchy and unstable.  It does not matter what origin you are rotating about.  If there is some way that you can move the head without the points changing, this is a problem, and the solver will be unstable.

Also, you need to be aware when there are more than one possible solve positions for the same group of points.  If you provide a good initial guess for the position, it will usually find the correct solve for you.  Sometimes the solver can alternate back a forth between different solutions if it does not start out close to the right solution.

Comment: By "providing a good initial guess", I understand you to mean giving solvePnP some pre-generated values. Does this mean setting solvePnP to useExtrinsicGuess and give it an rvec and tvec initialized to some values (ex. rotations = 0, translations = 0)?